# Meteor job collection should NOT run on weekends (sat/sun)

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-collections

I use this in my job-collection

```
later.parse.text('at 3:15 pm on Mon,Tues,Weds,Thurs and Fri');
```

what is the right solution

Comment: Does this solution not work?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution per the [docs](https://bunkat.github.io/later/parsers.html#text)

`later.parse.text('at 3:15 pm every weekday');`

Comment: Did you try this, I can't solve this with your solution

Answer (score 2):

In addition you can do

```
later.parse.recur().on('15:45').time().onWeekday()
```

Comment: NO man, I read the docs and implement in my project but not working @Fred